¿Cómo puedo guardar datos de una aplicación android en una base de datos en workbench de un server local sin internet?
ocupo ayuda, alguien sabe como puedo guardar datos en una base de datos en workbench de un server local sin internet? tengo entendido que si estas conectado a la red, puedes enviar datos de esa forma pero no se como se hace, agradezco de antemano.

Workbench? Es un programa que te permite conectar a un servidor de base de datos. Puedes tener una base de datos sin tener Workbench. El único requisito es tener MySQL Server. Para poder comunicarte con el servidor necesitas como mínimo estar en la misma red.

okey gracias, pero como se puede conectar, soy medio nuevo en esto.

Quieres guardar datos desde un dispositivo movil a un servidor que no tiene internet?? te refieres a hacerlo fisicamente?

Saludos. Como ambiente de pruebas es posible; el dispositivo donde ejecutas la aplicación debe estar conectada a la misma red (digamos y dependiendo la conexión por WiFi o Cable de Red) y colocar la IP (y los datos de autenticación requeridos) donde esta alojada la BD (no entro en detalles de configuración de red y/o server y/o BD). Aaah! y Workbench no es un BD es un GUI.

Bienvenido, revisar [ask], saludos.

okey, gracias por su ayuda
